# Outputting data from a for loop

Tags: php

Can you please help me in getting data out of this for loop. It actually should print the names of 3 months, which it does if i dont use the $ period variable in there and use echo instead. But I want to put the value into the $period variable, so I can use it else where in my script. Right now, it print out only one month.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
  {
  $period = '<option value="">';
  $period .= date('F, Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' month'));
  $period .= '</option>';
  }         

  echo $period;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overwriting the value of $period on each iteration. Try the code below:

```
$period = "";
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    $period .= '<option value="">';
    $period .= date('F, Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' month'));
    $period .= '</option>';
}         

echo $period;
```

Comment: Your answer it as correct as mine, but with a different solution. +1

Answer (score 3):

you need to output the value of your `$period` with each iteration.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    $period = '<option value="">';
    $period .= date('F, Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' month'));
    $period .= '</option>';
    echo $period;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$numPeriods = 3;
$period = '';

for($i=1; $i<=$numPeriods; $i++)
{
    $period .= '<option value="'.$i.'">';
    $period .= date('F, Y', strtotime('+'.$i .' month'));
    $period .= '</option>';
} 

echo $period;
```